# How can I declare global Error type in typescript NodeJs Architect project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, lambda, error-handling, architect

**Context**

Hi, I have a NodeJs+Ts+[Architect](https://github.com/architect/architect) setup for building and deploying lambda functions. Architect uses typescript [plugin](https://github.com/architect/plugin-typescript) to compile typescript. I am trying to use Error class to throw errors.

However, Typescript is picking up Error type from
`/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts`.

In the image below, please note the constructor signature only accepts `message` field. And the error interface does not have an `options` object either. Please
look at [Browser Error Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) or [NodeJs Error Class](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors) to see the signatures.

[image]

Node Error has the following constructor signature and Error interface.

[image]

**Problem**

- Getting TS Error for trying to use constructor signature of Node Error as Typescript is reading Error type from lib.es5.d.ts which accepts only 1 argument
  [image]

**Possible Solutions which I know**

- Declare global Error type ( Need help here. Since Architect is compiling TS using its plugin, I am not able to declare and override Error interface )
- Use your own Error class

I hope the question made sense. Would appreciate if there is a nicer way to solve this, but I am not getting ample discussions on Architect+Ts+NodeJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cause` option was introduced in `ES2022`. You would need to use at least that version for your lib types.

Change the `lib` version in your `tsconfig.json` to:

```json
"compilerOptions": { "lib": ["es2022"] }
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. However, I changed the lib version in tsconfig, I can also see lib.es2022.d.ts file in the same directory. but when I run tsc file.ts, it still errors out with the same error. Do I need to reference this config file as well if I am running tsc global?

Comment: @alchemist95 - you could try to manually specify the `tsconfig.son` with `tsc --project ./your_path/tsconfig.json`. Maybe try also changing the target version to `es2022`?